# How to stack html elements two by two

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, frontend

I'm building this frontend and am using cards to display some data, four of them in total. So I searched for someone's HTML card codepen and found one to use. But now I need to change the CSS to have the cards stacked instead of in a row. Can someone help me edit this code snippet?

It looks like this right now:

[image]

But I want the last two stacked on top of the first two.

The codepen is:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/eduarde/pen/MWwvbjL)
https://codepen.io/eduarde/pen/MWwvbjL

```css
.c-dashboardInfo {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.c-dashboardInfo .wrap {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 2px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 40px 25px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
.c-dashboardInfo__title,
.c-dashboardInfo__subInfo {
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-size: 1.18em;
}
.c-dashboardInfo span {
  display: block;
}
.c-dashboardInfo__count {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 64px;
  color: #323c43;
}
.c-dashboardInfo .wrap:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
}

.c-dashboardInfo:nth-child(1) .wrap:after {
  background: linear-gradient(82.59deg, #00c48c 0%, #00a173 100%);
}
.c-dashboardInfo:nth-child(2) .wrap:after {
  background: linear-gradient(81.67deg, #0084f4 0%, #1a4da2 100%);
}
.c-dashboardInfo:nth-child(3) .wrap:after {
  background: linear-gradient(69.83deg, #0084f4 0%, #00c48c 100%);
}
.c-dashboardInfo:nth-child(4) .wrap:after {
  background: linear-gradient(81.67deg, #ff647c 0%, #1f5dc5 100%);
}
.c-dashboardInfo__title svg {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-root-19 {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  user-select: none;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container pt-5">
    <div class="row align-items-stretch">
      <div class="c-dashboardInfo col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="wrap">
          <h4 class="heading heading5 hind-font medium-font-weight c-dashboardInfo__title">Portfolio Balance<svg
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root-19" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
              <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z">
              </path>
            </svg></h4><span class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__count">€10,500</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-dashboardInfo col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="wrap">
          <h4 class="heading heading5 hind-font medium-font-weight c-dashboardInfo__title">Rental income<svg
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root-19" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
              <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z">
              </path>
            </svg></h4><span class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__count">€500</span><span
            class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__subInfo">Last month: €30</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-dashboardInfo col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="wrap">
          <h4 class="heading heading5 hind-font medium-font-weight c-dashboardInfo__title">Available funds<svg
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root-19" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
              <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z">
              </path>
            </svg></h4><span class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__count">€5000</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-dashboardInfo col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="wrap">
          <h4 class="heading heading5 hind-font medium-font-weight c-dashboardInfo__title">Rental return<svg
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root-19" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
              <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z">
              </path>
            </svg></h4><span class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__count">6,40%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two rows of two elements, then you have to modify your html code.
You must use 2 different div which serves as a row.

```css
.c-dashboardInfo {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.c-dashboardInfo .wrap {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 2px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 40px 25px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
.c-dashboardInfo__title,
.c-dashboardInfo__subInfo {
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-size: 1.18em;
}
.c-dashboardInfo span {
  display: block;
}
.c-dashboardInfo__count {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 64px;
  color: #323c43;
}
.c-dashboardInfo .wrap:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
}

.c-dashboardInfo:nth-child(1) .wrap:after {
  background: linear-gradient(82.59deg, #00c48c 0%, #00a173 100%);
}
.c-dashboardInfo:nth-child(2) .wrap:after {
  background: linear-gradient(81.67deg, #0084f4 0%, #1a4da2 100%);
}
.c-dashboardInfo:nth-child(3) .wrap:after {
  background: linear-gradient(69.83deg, #0084f4 0%, #00c48c 100%);
}
.c-dashboardInfo:nth-child(4) .wrap:after {
  background: linear-gradient(81.67deg, #ff647c 0%, #1f5dc5 100%);
}
.c-dashboardInfo__title svg {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-root-19 {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  user-select: none;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container pt-5">
    <div class="row align-items-stretch">
      <div class="c-dashboardInfo col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="wrap">
          <h4 class="heading heading5 hind-font medium-font-weight c-dashboardInfo__title">Portfolio Balance<svg
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root-19" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
              <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z">
              </path>
            </svg></h4><span class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__count">€10,500</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-dashboardInfo col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="wrap">
          <h4 class="heading heading5 hind-font medium-font-weight c-dashboardInfo__title">Rental income<svg
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root-19" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
              <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z">
              </path>
            </svg></h4><span class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__count">€500</span><span
            class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__subInfo">Last month: €30</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-stretch">
      <div class="c-dashboardInfo col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="wrap">
          <h4 class="heading heading5 hind-font medium-font-weight c-dashboardInfo__title">Available funds<svg
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root-19" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
              <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z">
              </path>
            </svg></h4><span class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__count">€5000</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-dashboardInfo col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="wrap">
          <h4 class="heading heading5 hind-font medium-font-weight c-dashboardInfo__title">Rental return<svg
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root-19" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
              <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z">
              </path>
            </svg></h4><span class="hind-font caption-12 c-dashboardInfo__count">6,40%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing you have to change is

```
<div id="root">
  <div class="container pt-5">
    <div class="row align-items-stretch">
      <div class="c-dashboardInfo col-lg-6 col-md-6">
```

do you see `col-lg-6`?
that is what your code should look like,
go to your code and change ALL `col-lg-3` to `col-lg-6` , and you are done